# Update file content on Google Drive with .NET

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to add text in specific file content.

I used:

```
  var file = await dataService.Files.Get(fileId).ExecuteAsync();
  if (file == null)
  {
    throw new Exception(nameof(fileId));
  }

  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
      sw.Write(content); //there is a simple text like: bblablllbalblba

      var request = dataService.Files.Update(file, fileId, stream, file.MimeType);
      await request.UploadAsync();
    }
  }
```

but seems that content is not updated/written. I don't get any error.

Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: You can download the file and edit it locally or you can try the google docs api which will let you edit google document.

Comment: Step through code and see if you get to all the instructions.

Comment: @jdweng What does mean to get all the instructions ?

Comment: You may be getting an exception and not executing all the code.

Comment: check if you need to rewind the memory stream? (see `seek` in docs)

Comment: What is `dataService`?